# Flask with SQLite Encoding Issue

Tags: python, sqlite, encoding, flask

I have the following code that is inserting JSON data into an SQLite database:

```
# POST request here
if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
    db = get_db()
    db.execute('insert into places (lat, long, address, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', [request.data[0], request.data[1], request.data[2], request.data[3]])
    db.commit()
```

and to retrieve that data:

```
# GET request here
if request.method == 'GET':
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select * from places order by id')
    entries = [dict(id=row[0], lat=row[1], long=row[2], address=row[3], name=row[4]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return repr(entries)
```

and my `get_db()` method used above:

```
def get_db():
    op = _app_ctx_stack.top
    if not hasattr(top, 'sqlite_db'):
        top.sqlite_db = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    return top.sqlite_db
```

Here is a sample cURL request that I'm doing:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/location -d '{'lat':5, 'long':10, 'address':'street', 'name':'work'}'
```

When trying to do a `GET` as follows: `curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/location`, I get:

```
[{'lat': u'{', 'address': u'a', 'id': 1, 'long': u'l', 'name': u't'}]
```

I believe that that is an encoding issue. Any advice on how I'm supposed to store the data to avoid this? What exactly is the issue here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is a fully functioning version of what you are trying to achieve. There were a number of places that were causing issues. They are as follows:

**curl issue**

the json string you had used single quotes, this is invalid json. json strings must use double quotes. The correct call should be:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5000/location -d '{"lat":5, "long":10, "address":"street", "name":"work"}'
```

I faced this issue in the code when I tried to decode the json data, because it was invalid json the decoding initially failed.

**inserting data issue**

in your code you were referencing `request.data[0]` which in fact was the first character of your json data which happened to be `{` character which is why you kept seeing that as the value of the lat field. In the code below `request.data` is referenced and deserialized into a python dictionary. Then we can insert a database row by accessing each of the required fields. To create the database used in this code you may run this:

```
echo "CREATE TABLE places (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, lat text, long text, address text, name  text);" | sqlite3 places.db
```

the response that you will get when you visit `http://127.0.0.1:5000/location` will be:

```
[(1, u'5', u'10', u'street', u'work')]
```

**code**

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json, sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/location', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("places.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM places ORDER BY id')
        return repr(cur.fetchall())
    else:
        d = json.loads(request.data)
        row = (d['lat'], d['long'], d['address'], d['name'])
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO places (lat, long, address, name)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?)""", row)
        conn.commit()
        return 'done\n'

app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
repr(x).decode("utf-8") where x is your value
```

Comment: That didn't work. What's the best way to store the data to avoid this?

Comment: can you try this before storing the data ? so if you want to store x, use this.

Comment: I tried doing: `request.data = repr(request.data).decode("utf-8")` before get = get_db() in POST but it still does not work. Is that the right way?

Comment: Would you recommend using SQLAlchemy instead?